# do while loop won't run awk

Tags: loops, awk

I am currently trying to get to grips with writing awk scripts, however, I'm running into issues with do...while loops.

```
    -bash-3.00$ cat basicloop.awk
    BEGIN { count = 1
            do {
            print "stuff"
            } while ( count != 1 )
    }
```

When I run it:

-bash-3.00$ awk -f basicloop.awk
awk: syntax error near line 3
awk: illegal statement near line 3
awk: syntax error near line 5
awk: bailing out near line 5

```
    {
        count=1
        do {
            print "I get printed at least once no matter what" 
        } while ( count != 1 )
    }
```

awk: syntax error near line 3
awk: illegal statement near line 3
awk: syntax error near line 5
awk: bailing out near line 5

As you can see, these are both very simple do...while loops and I don't know why they're running into issues. The latter is taken directly from: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-awk2/ and the former is my take on it.

```
    -bash-3.00$ nawk -f basicloop.awk
    stuff
```

Running the exact same files in nawk seems to get them to work fine, however, as can be seen above and below.

```
    I get printed at least once no matter what
```

The workaround is obviously to run them in nawk, but I'd sooner understand whatever the issue is and fix it (if possible) rather than simply ignore it.

Comment: Cannot reproduce your syntax errors on my version of awk (GNU Awk 4.1.1)

Comment: ...or GNU Awk 3.1.8, or Mawk 1.2. Are you running this script on two different systems? If so, are you sure that the script files are the same? Are there any weird characters in there?

Comment: Running them on the same system and haven't moved directories since making and running them. I'm using awk, not gawk or nawk. As per the example, it runs in nawk but not awk, which is what's confusing me.

Comment: Not sure how to check the version of awk that I'm running it with, if you can point me in the right direction I'll try to get that, in case it helps.

Comment: `awk --version` will give the version.  You can also check `which awk` and see what it's pointing to.

Comment: awk --version doesn't return anything for me. which awk points me at /usr/bin/awk, and there is awk, nawk and oawk in the bin, however, I've been using awk, hence 'awk -f basicloop.awk', that doesn't tell me the version number though.

Comment: Looks like you're on a really old system, where it's quite possible that `awk` points to `oawk` (try `ls -l "$(which awk)"`). If that's the case, then you've probably just found something that's broken in `oawk`, which isn't a great deal of a surprise :)

Comment: That seems to be the case then, thank you very much for your help!